# Wait for the first future to complete in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous

Say I have two futures corresponding to two parallelly executed computation. How do I wait until the first future is ready? Ideally, I'm looking for an API similar to [Python asyncio's wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#waiting-primitives) with the parameter `return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED`.

However, as far as I can gather, the current C++ `std::future` functionality seems to not offer such an API. In that case, I'm looking for an efficient/correct method to poll for the future's status.

In case futures aren't the right tool for this task, I'm open to solutions using threads and conditional variables.

Comment: std::future_status status = future->wait_for(0); ?

Comment: You might retrieve the result of execution from that future with `std::future<T>::get()` function. It will wait for a valid result from a future.

Comment: Just curious but this seems an odd requirement.  If there is a task that can be started when, for example, the first future is ready then why not just include that task in the thread associated with that future?  As it stands this seems a bit XY.  Do you have a use case for this?

Comment: @G.M. To clarify, the requirement is to perform a task as soon as any of the two tasks complete (rather than first task/future). My current use case is in the implementation of a protocol where Alice and Bob send Charlie the same data and Charlie continues with computation as soon as he receives the data from either Alice or Bob without waiting for both of them to send it. I believe this is a general way to combine futures provided in most languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to come up with a function that takes two futures `f1` and `f2` and returns a new future which is resolved to either `f1` or `f2` depending on which completes first.

The function assumes that the `get()` method is not called on `f1` and `f2` anywhere (else we'll need to use `std::shared_future`).

```
#include <unistd.h>

#include <array>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

template <typename T>
class WaitFirstData {
 public:
  T res;
  bool res_ready;
  std::condition_variable res_cv;
  std::mutex res_mutex;

  WaitFirstData() : res_ready{false} {}
};

template <typename T>
std::future<T> wait_first(std::future<T> f1, std::future<T> f2) {
  auto data = std::make_shared<WaitFirstData<T>>();

  std::promise<T> wait_first_promise;
  std::future<T> wait_first_future = wait_first_promise.get_future();

  std::thread wait_first_thread{
      [](std::promise<T> p, std::shared_ptr<WaitFirstData<T>> data) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(data->res_mutex);
        data->res_cv.wait(lk, [&]() { return data->res_ready; });

        p.set_value(data->res);
      },
      std::move(wait_first_promise), data};

  auto thread_lambda = [](std::future<T> f,
                          std::shared_ptr<WaitFirstData<T>> data) {
    T r = f.get();

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(data->res_mutex);
    if (!data->res_ready) {
      data->res_ready = true;
      data->res = r;
      data->res_cv.notify_one();
    }
  };

  std::thread t1{thread_lambda, std::move(f1), data},
      t2{thread_lambda, std::move(f2), data};

  wait_first_thread.detach();
  t1.detach();
  t2.detach();

  return wait_first_future;
}

// arbitrary function denoting a potentially long-running task
int func(int n) {
  sleep(n);
  return n;
}

int main() {
  auto f1 = std::async(std::launch::async, func, 2);
  auto f2 = std::async(std::launch::async, func, 15);

  // f3 is resolved as soon as either f1 or f2 completes (with the same return
  // value too)
  auto f3 = wait_first(std::move(f1), std::move(f2));

  // wait for f3 to resolve
  int l = f3.get();

  // computation (here I/O) done after the first among f1 and f2 is completed
  std::cout << "Task done after " << l << " seconds" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::experimental::future` method `then` if your computation is sequential (one depends on other), if you have access to `std::experimental::future` (and not afraid of using "experimental")

You can also pass one future as parameter to second computation right away. `future::get` is a way to wait for future to complete. Use `std::shared_future`, if you need to pass the first future to somewhere else.

Comment: Even in 2023 my GCC doesn't seem to have that - GCC 13.1.0